# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find a limit of a sequence:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

I tried to divide numerator and denominator by n, but it didn't help, as the limit became $\frac{0}{0}$. I tried other things, but always got an indefinite limit. I know that the limit is 0, but I just don't know how to show it. It's probably something really simple, but I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Hint: it doesn't go to 0.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I put it in wrong! I'll edit it!

Comment: Is this not -1?

Comment: The bottom seems irrelevant, it may still be typed incorrectly. I would use Maclaurin series, though L'Hospital's Rule also works well.

Comment: The whole numerator, sorry if I put it in wrong

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Do you know about $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac 1 x \sin (x) $ ?

Comment: I don't think I do, I'm trying to figure out Daniel's answer right now.

Comment: @Robert : got to know that, it is the microwave solution to many limit problems.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x} - 1}{1+x}$$
Using the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, we get the result
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x} - 1}{1+x}=\frac{1-1}{1}=0$$